# Expression edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am working on a report in asp.net, mvc/c# and in my report i want to display the date without the time so instead of

12/3/2011 00:00:00 ------ to ------ 12/3/2011

and i am using this expression for my text box that is displaying the date:

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!DateClosed.Value)
```

and for an item with a date it does show properly without the time - but for other items in the list which do not have date they display the time like so: 12:00:00 AM

How can i fix the expression so that it will only show the date only when there is a date to display and not show the time when a date is not available.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  You have some items that do not have dates, and you do not want anything to appear.  But you have items that do have dates, for which you only want the dates to appear?

Comment: @Carl Benson Correct, I have items in a list some of them have a date which appear fine with the current expression that i have. But for items that don't have a Date the time appears : 12:00:00 AM and i don't want anything to appear if there isn't a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i played around with this and i used a different format expression which lucky enough worked well. Thanks for everyone how helped.

```
=Format(Fields!DateClosed.Value, "d")
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
=(DateClosed==null) ? FormatDateTime(DateClosed) : string.Empty;
```

Also, you might use

```
=(DateClosed==null) ? DateClosed.Value.ToString("mm dd yyyy") : string.Empty;
```

instead of calling a separate `FormatDateTime()` function (unless, of course, you need to centralize date formatting, but that could be handled by storing the format in web.config).

Or even

```
string FormatDateTime(DateTime? date)
{
    var result = date==null ? date.ToString("mm dd yyyy") : string.Empty;
}
```

if you don't want to put the ternary conditional in the markup.

Comment: Thanks for the help this looked very good and helpful to use but for the textbox expression in the report viewer it didn't like the colon expression but i know this is very useful for other parts of the app which i will use it in. Thanks

Comment: This worked also in my report: =Format(Fields!DateClosed.Value, "d")

Answer (score 0):

Check if the date is null and if it is then set `string.Empty`